# How to submit a field inside a hidden dialog in MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an MVC 3 form in a strongly typed view where one of the fields I need submitted is inside of a jQuery dialog.  I have not been able to get this field to be part of the POST parameters submitted.  Why oh why?

The View:

```
@model My.Models.DialogFieldModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#aDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 250, width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok!": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostDialogField", "DialogField"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.message)

        <div id="aDialog">
            <h3>Fill in this message!</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.message)
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Message" /></p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

The Model:

```
using System;

namespace My.Models
{
    public class DialogFieldModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String message { get; set; }

        public DialogFieldModel()
        {
            message = "Default";
        }
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WellTrkd.Models;

namespace My.Controllers
{
    public class DialogFieldController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DialogFieldModel dfm = new DialogFieldModel(); // set default message
            return View(dfm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostDialogField(DialogFieldModel dfm)
        {
            String message = dfm.message;
            if (message != "Default")
                //Yay!
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            else // Boo
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately the #message field is never submitted along with the rest of the HTML POST parameters (checked in network tab of chrome dev view) unless I take it out of the dialog.  The result is that in the PostDialogField action dfm.message contains the "Default" string, even if I've changed the message in the dialog.

I know I could add a hidden field to the form that is kept synchronized with the field in the dialog, but I feel I'm missing something.  Any thoughts oh wise ones?

Comment: what type is the message field? a boolean?

Comment: if you are using strongly typed view are  you sure the `ID` is populated, because it sounds like a create view and the `ID` would be empty when you are inserting a new record

Comment: @Dallas I edited my question to specify that the message field is a String in the corresponding Model.  I would ideally like to mark the field as Datatype.MultilineText and have it show up as a textarea.

Comment: @3nigma Yes I can see why it would seem like a create view but it is indeed an edit view, our invoices go through several states (rejected, approved, pending, etc..) and are saved along with each state change.

Comment: what happens if you don't use the javascript to submit the form and sumbit it normally?

Comment: check with the firebug does the hidden field contains the value for the id

Comment: @Dallas Nope, a normal form submit doesn't pick up the #Message either.  I added a line in $(document).ready() to automatically fill in the field, confirmed it with $('#Message).val(), but the form still won't include it in the POST parameters

Comment: @3nigma Confirmed the id is indeed there.

Comment: How does the `saveInvoice` method look like?

Comment: Can you clarify that you have seen that the field is not included in the POST request, and it is not a modelBinding issue.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The saveInvoice method is irrelevant.  Even when removing the onclick event from the submit button, not showing the dialog at all, filling in the field with javascript on page load, and submitting the form regularly (no js involved), the problem persists.  I edited the question to clarify this a bit.

Comment: @DanielGill, please show a full example illustrating the problem. Narrow down and remove all unnecessary parts but keep the essentials things. At the moment the situation you described is status no-repro for me. So: models, controllers, views, scripts allowing to repro it. Obviously you would hardcode all values in the models to make it easier to reproduce without having to setup databases and stuff.

Comment: @Dallas When viewing the post requests in the 'Network' tab of Chrome's developer view, under the section 'Form Data' I see a list of the POST parameters sent - ID, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber etc... - but never my Message parameter unless the field is placed outside of the dialog.

Comment: Can you show us the generated html?

Comment: What happens if you move the hidden field inside the dialog?

Comment: @kay.herzam Moving the hidden ID field inside the dialog removes it from the resulting POST parameter list as well.

Comment: The dialog is absolutely positioned. do fields in an absolutely positioned container get removed from the Form?

Comment: A quick test showed that absolutely positioned fields do not get excluded.

Comment: Question:  I have rewritten my question entirely by including a full, completely stripped down example.  Should I edit this question (which would make most of these comments irrelevant), or ask a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the element you turn into a dialog is moved out of the form towards a new dialog-element at the bottom of the DOM. And since it's not part of the form any more, it won't be submitted when the form is submitted.

If you'd destroy the dialog when closing it, it would be moved back to where it was, but I can't see if that's what is desired. The other option is to sync elements.

Comment: You are correct, the dialog is moved out of the form, not sure how I missed that earlier :)  Destroying it with $(this).dialog("destroy") in the 'OK!' button does not move it back within the form.  I guess syncing a hidden field is the only option?